# Attempt to index global 'application' (a nil value) error

Tags: lua

I'm trying to follow a Lua roguelike course to learn the language and by line 17 when I had attempted to run the program to see the title it came up with the error

```
lua: [string "<eval>"]:1: attempt to index global 'application' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
        [string "<eval>"]:1: in main chunk
```

Here's all the code I've written and the link to the course

```
application:setOrientation(Application.LANDSCAPE_LEFT

application:setScaleMode("letterbox")

BLACK @ 0x1A1A1A 
application:setBackgroundColor(BLACK)

local fg = Bitmap.new(Texture.new("images/foreground.png", true))
fg:setX(1201)
stage:addChild(fg)

YELLOW @ 0xDAD45E 
local title = TextField.new(nil, "The Long Dark") 
title:setTextColor(YELLOW) 
title:setPosition(1320, 100)
stage:addChild(title)
```

https://programmingbymoonlight.com/roguelike-part-1-lua-and-gideros-an-introduction/

Comment: How are you running your code?

Comment: did you declare the `application` object before?

Comment: I was using repl.it but that was on my laptop I'm on my PC now and I can use ZeroBrane or gideros as it says, and no I haven't declared application.

Comment: I guess my question is what would I write to declare ```application``` as a global value

Comment: I asked the creator of the tutorial about how it's declared or if it's a part of gideros.

Comment: it is part of Gideros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I tried gideros and it worked properly, while it depends on lua it has it's own commands native to it's IDE framework.